# PHP foreach $key + 1

Tags: php, foreach, addition

I try to add "1" to the key of my string.

So here is what i got so far. I try with $key+1;

**This is my Code**

```
<?php foreach ($this->titles as $key => $title) : ?>
   <li class="<?php echo $this->tabs . ' tab_' . $key; ?>"><a href="#tab-<?php echo $key; ?>"><?php echo $title; ?></a></li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

So i get 0,1,2,3,4,.. . But what i need is 1,2,3,4,5....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply add 1 to the key before echoing:

```
<?php foreach ($this->titles as $key => $title) : ?>
  <li class="<?php echo $this->tabs . ' tab_' . ($key + 1); ?>">
    <a href="#tab-<?php echo ($key + 1); ?>"><?php echo $title; ?></a>
  </li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this...

```
<li class="<?php echo $this->tabs . ' tab_' . ($key+1); ?>">
    <a href="#tab-<?php echo ($key+1); ?>">
        <?php echo $title; ?>
    </a>
</li>
```

Hopefully your keys are numeric, because if they're random string keys you're likely to wind up with every output being `1`

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php foreach ($this->titles as $key => $title) : ?>
   <li class="<?php echo $this->tabs . ' tab_' . ++$key; ?>"><a href="#tab-<?php echo $key; ?>"><?php echo $title; ?></a></li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Should perform best (by a tiny fraction of a tiny fraction of a tiny fraction)